# How to pass variable to do external action but not command parameter in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to do a output redirection in bash for passing variable in shell.

For example:

```
OPTION=">> /tmp/log1 2>&1"
ADD_OPTION=($OPTION)
ls ${ADD_OPTION[@]}
```

I want to record result of `ls` command in **/tmp/log1**.
So as to, `ls >> /tmp/log1 2>&1` to be executed.

But unfortunately, `${ADD_OPTION[@]}` was treated as parameter of `ls`.
The actual result is:

```
ls: >>: No such file or directory
ls: /tmp/log1: No such file or directory
ls: 2>&1: No such file or directory
```

What should I do for it?

Comment: Additionally , bash -c "ls ${ADD_OPTION[@]}" could be executed for the goal. But for the reason of other needs,  I want an another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
eval ls ${OPTION}
```

As an obvious note, be careful with `eval`.

**Example:**

```
$ OPTION=">> /tmp/log1 2>&1"

$ eval ls ${OPTION}

$ cat /tmp/log1 
1
2
3
```

Comment: `eval` is fine, but be vigilant in its use. You would not want to do `cmd="sudo rm -rf /forms"` and `eval ${cmd/forms/}`...

Answer (score 0):

```
eval $(echo "ls ${ADD_OPTION[@]}")
```

is probably what you want to do